# Taking frequent screenshots with Java 

Tags: java, screenshot

I have this code for taking a screenshot; how could I change it to take and buffer a screenshot every second?

```
{
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    search: for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (amongst other things) use the [Timer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) in the JDK, for example:

```
Timer t = new Timer("Sceenshot timer");
    TimerTask screenShotTask  = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Call your code
        }
    };
    t.schedule(screenShotTask, 1000);
```